# How to evaluate the integral $\int_C \frac{dz}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having difficulty evaluating the integral $\int_C \frac{dz}{e^z-1}$ where $C$ is the complex unit circle. I know this can be done using the residue theorem, but I've encountered the integral before the section on the residue theorem. By using the usual parameterization the unit circle, we can turn this into
$$i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{e^{it}}-1}\;dt.$$
This does not seem like progress. Are there any other approaches I could take without the residue theorem?

Comment: $e^z-1 = z f(z)$ where $f(0) = 1$ and $f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is analytic on $|z| < 2$. Thus $$\int_C \frac{dz}{e^z-1} =\int_C \frac{dz}{z f(z)} = \int_C (\frac{1}{z f(z)}-\frac{1}{z })dz+\int_C \frac{1}{z }dz = 2i \pi$$ since $g(z ) = \frac{1}{z f(z)}-\frac{1}{z } = \frac{1-f(z)}{z f(z)}$ is holomorphic on $|z| < 2$ and (by the Cauchy integral theorem) $\int_C g(z)dz = 0$

Comment: (note how this is 100% equivalent to re-proving the residue theorem)

Comment: How does it follow from the Cauchy integral theorem that $\int_C g(z)\;dz =0$ when $g(z)$ has a pole at $z=0$?

Comment: as I said $g(z) = \frac{1-f(z)}{z f(z)}$ doesn't have any pole on $|z| < 2$

Comment: I was mistaken. This makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to say $f(z)$ doesn't have any zero (on $|z| < 2\pi$)

Comment: Is it also correct to use the Cauchy integral formula: $$\int_C\frac{dz}{e^z-1}\;dz=\int_C\frac{f(x)^{-1}}{z}\;dz=2\pi if(0)^{-1}=2\pi i?$$

Comment: yes of course, well what I wrote is more or less how you prove it from the Cauchy integral theorem